# Opencv C++ Raspberry Pi Crashes

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

Ive been stuck with this problem for a few days and I thought I'd ask for help.
I have written this test code to display my issue

this is my take picture function

```
cv::Mat takePicture(){
    cv::Mat pic;
    VideoCapture cam(0);
    if(!cam.isOpened()){
        std::cout << "Failed to make connection to Cam" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
    cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    cam >> pic;
    cvWaitKey(100);
    return pic.clone();
}
```

this is a loop in my main function that will cause a crash

```
if(test_mode == true){
    while(true){
        Mat testImg;
        char fileName[50];
        sprintf(fileName, "testFile%d", threadNo);
        testImg = takePicture();
        cout << "current pic is " << threadNo << endl;
        threadNo++;
        testImg.release();
    }
}
```

The program will run fine until image 27 it will then go slower and by image 30 I will get a variety of errors they are

```
mmap: Cannot allocate memory
munmap: Invalid argument
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
libv4l1: error allocating v4l1 buffers: Cannot allocate memory
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Mapping Memmory from video source error: Invalid argument
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Initial Capture Error: Unable to load initial memory buffers
*** glibc detected *** ./Cam: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0076ab88 *** 
Aborted
```

I keep thinking this must be caused by a leak. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: are you using an usb camera or the pi cam module ?

Comment: usb the Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000

Comment: This code runs fine on Windows 8, with Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.5. It doesn't appear to have any leaks. Is this the actual code that you are running?

Comment: Yes this is the only code. Ontop of that is just cin >> test_mode and an initial check to make sure the camera is connected. Below that code segment is the actual program Ive written but it would next get executed if test_mode is true. I'm starting to think this is a Pi related issue. Maybe it doesnt like my webcam

Comment: i don't think, it's a good idea to open a new capture object for *every* frame you want to grab.

Comment: Berak turns out that was the issue. Thanks